# How to remap C-x prefix in emacs to a dedicated key?

Tags: emacs

Many emacs commands start with C-x or C-c. I found that I never use the right shift key. So I was thinking if it's possible to remap C-x to Shift. To open a file, I can do Shift-Ctrl-f instead of C-x C-f. Here I would prefer Shift-Ctrl-f than Shift Ctrl-f.

Comment: Are you using Windows, Mac, or a Linux / BSD variety with X windows, or the Linux or BSD console, or a plain TTY connection (like that offered by SSH) between machines? Whether you can detect a press of a meta key like Shift depends heavily on which method you are using to talk to Emacs. Across a TTY connection, for example, it is simply not possible.

Comment: I use emacs on a remote Linux machine and I connect to that machine over ssh in iTerm2 on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

The link created by SSH between machines does not transmit the pressing and releasing of the shift key; only when another key is pressed in conjunction with Shift is a character transmitted, and the character — upper case H when Shift and “h” have been pressed, for example — looks the same to the remote machine whether left or right shift was used.

Therefore, to make right Shift visible, you will have to tell the terminal program to consider it to be a different key — or maybe even have to tell the Mac system settings that it is no longer Shift?

Is it possible to explain to your Mac that pressing Shift sends the character Control-X? That would kill both birds with one stone!